# Custom Accepted Operation in Drag and Drop

Tags: c#, uwp, drag-and-drop, uwp-xaml, user-feedback

I am making a library management software. This is the screenshot:
[image: screenshot]

I have implementing functionalities like dragging a book into the delete icon to delete the book. But there are two obstacles:

1. DataPackageOperation has only four possibilities: Copy, link, move none. So, after four, it is difficult to differentiate which AppBarButton is the book dropped on.
2. I plan to add more items to the CommandBar. But there are only four possible operations

I need a way to give the user a custom feedback as to which AppBarButton is the book currently dragged over. DataPackageOperation contains only four. Out of which, 'None' cannot be used(because it will be confusing). Is there a way to provide that feedback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need a way to give the user a custom feedback as to which AppBarButton is the book currently dragged over

You could give the user a custom feedback via custom Drag UI. The follow code comes from [`XamlDragAndDrop`](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlDragAndDrop) official code sample.

```
private void TargetTextBox_DragEnter(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.DragEventArgs e)
{
    /// Change the background of the target
    VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Inside", true);
    bool hasText = e.DataView.Contains(StandardDataFormats.Text);
    e.AcceptedOperation = hasText ? DataPackageOperation.Copy : DataPackageOperation.None;
    if (hasText)
    {
        e.DragUIOverride.Caption = "Drop here to insert text";
        // Now customize the content
        if ((bool)HideRB.IsChecked)
        {
            e.DragUIOverride.IsGlyphVisible = false;
            e.DragUIOverride.IsContentVisible = false;
        }
        else if ((bool)CustomRB.IsChecked)
        {
            var bitmap = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/dropcursor.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
            // Anchor will define how to position the image relative to the pointer
            Point anchor = new Point(0,52); // lower left corner of the image
            e.DragUIOverride.SetContentFromBitmapImage(bitmap, anchor);
            e.DragUIOverride.IsGlyphVisible = false;
            e.DragUIOverride.IsCaptionVisible = false;
        }
        // else keep the DragUI Content set by the source
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: The answer can be simplified. "Just add this line in the drag enter function: `e.DragUIOverride.Caption = "some text"`